# Connecting two screws?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and I am looking for an easy way to connect two screws. Currently I have this double helix structure that I made by constructing two screws from circles:  [image]

I am looking to connect one of the sides of the double helix like this:

[image]

I've tried making a tube using a bezier circle/path but can't find a way to attach it to the ends of the screw easy and seamlessly.

Comment: Look at Bridge Edge loops https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops

Answer (score 2):

[image]Move both the ends of the helix toward their common centre using proportional editing, then remove doubles and adjust with proportional editing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I’ll have to figure out how to do that.